# Shiny - renderDataTable - bSearchable vs checkboxInput

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I´m having problems combining two features while building a data table:

1. I use “bSearchable” to select 1 column that I want to use the search tool to filter
2. I use "checkboxInput" to select the columns the user wants to see.

Both work separately, but not together. If I uncheck a column in my menu input, the data disappears - like applying a filter and no data was found. How can I fix this?

```
          library(shiny)    
runApp(list(ui=(fluidPage(
      pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel('Title'),
        sidebarPanel(
          helpText('Text about the table'),

          checkboxInput('columns','I want to select the columns' , value = FALSE),

          conditionalPanel(
            condition= "input.columns == true",
            checkboxGroupInput('show_vars', 'Select the columns that you want to see:', names(iris[1:4]),
                               selected =  names(iris[1:4]))
          ),

          downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'),width = 3

        ),
        mainPanel(
          tags$head(tags$style("tfoot {display: table-header-group;}")),
          dataTableOutput("mytable1"),width = 9

        )
      ))
    )

    ,

    server=(function(input, output) {

      library(ggplot2) 
      library(XLConnect)  

      #DATA 
      tabel<- reactive({
        iris[,c(input$show_vars,"Species"), drop = FALSE]

      })

      #   OUTPUT   
      output$mytable1 = renderDataTable({
        tabel()}, 
        options = list(    
          aoColumns = list(list(bSearchable = FALSE), list(bSearchable = FALSE),list(bSearchable = FALSE),
                           list(bSearchable = FALSE),list(bSearchable = TRUE)),
          bFilter=1, bSortClasses = 1,aLengthMenu = list(c(10,25,50, -1), list('10','25', '50', 'Todas')),iDisplayLength = 10
        )

      )

      output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() { paste('tabela_PSU','.xlsx', sep='') },
        content = function(file){
          fname <- paste(file,"xlsx",sep=".")
          wb <- loadWorkbook(fname, create = TRUE)
          createSheet(wb, name = "Sheet1")
          writeWorksheet(wb, tabel(), sheet = "Sheet1") 
          saveWorkbook(wb)
          file.rename(fname,file)
        },
      )


    })
    ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is by filtering the data `iris` based on `input$show_vars`, you are changing the number of columns of the DataTable. 
However, you have defined a **fixed** `aoColumns` option, which implies your DataTable has five columns (four non-searchable, one searchable).

Therefore, when you deselect any checkbox inputs, the filtered data doesn't match the specified options. As a result, nothing is displayed.

That is, although your data in the DataTable is **reactive**, the options, however, are **NOT reactive**.

If you read the [`renderDataTable`'s document](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderDataTable.html) carefully, you will see that you can pass two types of variables to the `options` argument:

> options   A list of initialization options to be passed to DataTables, or a function to return such a list.

The differences are:

- If you specify `options` as a list, Shiny assumes that the `options` are fixed; But since you are dynamically filtering the data based on `input$show_vars`, you **should** dynamically change the options for `aoColumns` as well.
- If you pass a function as an argument for `options`, Shiny will know that the `options` are also reactive. Hence Shiny will also update the `options` when the data (in your case, the `data.frame` encapsulated in the reactive variable named `tabel`) updates.

You may already know that **reactive variables** are themselves **functions**. They are evaluated in a reactive environment and when evaluated, they return the current state/value of the data. This is why you pass `tabel()` instead of `tabel` to `renderDataTable`.

The solution then, is to wrap the entire `options` list into a reactive variable (hence a function as well). Specifically, we want to dynmaically set the `aoColumns` option so that the number of `bSearchable` toggles matches the number of columns shown in the DataTable.

Below I only show the updated `server` part, since there's nothing needs to be changed in the UI part.

#### server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  library(ggplot2) 
  library(XLConnect)  

  #DATA 
  tabel<- reactive({
    iris[,c(input$show_vars,"Species"), drop = FALSE]

  })

  # wrap the `options` into a reactive variable (hence a function) so that it will
  # be evaluated dynamically when the data changes as well. 
  # `dt_options` is reactive in the sense that it will reflect the number of rows
  # visible based on the checkboxInput selections.

  dt_options <- reactive({
    # dynamically create options for `aoColumns` depending on how many columns are selected.
    toggles <- lapply(1:length(input$show_vars), function(x) list(bSearchable = F))
    # for `species` columns
    toggles[[length(toggles) + 1]] <- list(bSearchable = T)

    list(
      aoColumns = toggles,
      bFilter = 1, bSortClasses = 1, 
      aLengthMenu = list(c(10,25,50, -1), list('10','25', '50', 'Todas')),
      iDisplayLength = 10
      )
  })

  #   OUTPUT
  output$mytable1 = renderDataTable({
    tabel()}, 
    options = dt_options
  )

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste('tabela_PSU','.xlsx', sep='') },
    content = function(file){
      fname <- paste(file,"xlsx",sep=".")
      wb <- loadWorkbook(fname, create = TRUE)
      createSheet(wb, name = "Sheet1")
      writeWorksheet(wb, tabel(), sheet = "Sheet1") 
      saveWorkbook(wb)
      file.rename(fname,file)
    },
  )

})
```

(Note that I separate the UI part and server part into `ui.R` and `server.R`.)